# going through a list with a for loop

Tags: c#, list, struct

Okay, i have a list and where i have structs stored, and i need to go through them from the last to the first, to check if one of the variables in the struct is 1. the code look like this:

```
for(int i = (checkpoints.Count - 1); i == 0; i--)
{
    if(checkpoints[i].active == 1)
    {
        playerPositionX = checkpoints[i].xPosition;
        playerPositionY = checkpoints[i].yPosition;

        camPositionX = checkpoints[i].xPosition;

        break;
    }
}
```

this is the struct that i use:

```
private struct checkpoint
{
    public int xPosition;
    public int yPosition;
    public int active;
}
```

what i need to do is to check if the variable active is == 1 in the struct that i have stored in the list. i have around 3-8 structs stored in the list. I need to start the check from the last struct in the list and work my way to the first.

when i try to debug the program it looks like it's not going from the last, but it starts at i=0.

please leave a comment if you have a fix, or if you need more information.

Comment: `for(int i = (checkpoints.Count - 1); i == 0; i--)` Shouldn't your `i == 0` check actually be `i >= 0`?

Comment: One side note,if you only use the list to check in this situation(from last to first) consider a stack<T>.Also remember when you pass that list around,every element is passed(the whole struct) since its a value type,if considering performance you might wanna make a class(therefore the list will contain references).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake was that you said to go though the loop if **i** was equal to 0, when it wasn't. You want the loop to loop until **i** is greater or equal to zero.

```
for(int i = (checkpoints.Count - 1); i >= 0; i--)  // your mistake was here
{
    if(checkpoints[i].active == 1)
    {
        playerPositionX = checkpoints[i].xPosition;
        playerPositionY = checkpoints[i].yPosition;

        camPositionX = checkpoints[i].xPosition;

       break;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i don't know how i could miss that, it fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `LastOrDefault()` function. But, here can be one problem, because we are searching for `Struct`.

*If nothing found?*

`LastOrDefault()` will return `default(checkpoint)` if nothing found. The default value of a struct is the struct with all its values in turn default initialized. So, we must cast them to nullable using `.Cast<checkpoint?>`.

```
 var activeCheckPoint = checkpoints
      .Where(x => x.active == 1)
      .Cast<checkpoint?>()
      .LastOrDefault();
```

---

Or we must do the second check afterward that the returned object's active value is 1.

```
var activeCheckPoint = checkpoints.LastOrDefault(x => x.active == 1);
if(actactiveCheckPoint.active == 1)
{
    // Then it is Ok
}
else
{
     // Nothins was found
}
```

---

But, if you want to use `for` loop, then you must change `i == 0` to `i >= 0`.

Comment: This will iterate checkpoints from the start to the end, not end to the start. Need a call to LINQ's `Enumerable<T>.Reverse` first. EDIT: Or `LastOrDefault`, forgot about that one.

Comment: Actually, since `checkpoint` is a value type, this might be a bad idea. You would never know if `activeCheckPoint` was a returned hit or just a default `checkpoint` object since it can't return a `null` value (I suppose you could do a second check _afterward_ that the returned object's `active` value is `1` and not `0` though.